# Internet connection check not working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Here the code which i have used in my phonegap based application with sencha touch. I have tried with checking for internet connection availablity.The alert works only when conection available.When Internet connection failed it doesnot showing alert.Here the code

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang=en-US>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Cache-control content=no-cache />
    <meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes />
    <title>WishList</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" />
    <link href="resources/css/mobiscroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var a=navigator.onLine;
        if(a){
             alert('online');
        }else{
            Ext.Msg.alert("Alert!", "Please check your internet connection!");
        }
        </script>
    <script src="libraries/sencha/sencha-touch-all.js" defer></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery.1.10.1.js" defer></script>
    <script src="libraries/mobiscroll/mobiscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer>                 </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="app/views/app.js" defer></script>
    <script src="app/views/JSfunctions.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/cordova.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Whats the problem with the code?PLease help me

Comment: I'm not a phonegap expert but *alert()* is different from *Ext.Msg.alert()* in my book.

Comment: @Lame-up-duck i replaced `alert('Please check your internet connection!!!');` But still not working

Comment: Maybe you can find some help here: http://www.neotericdesign.com/blog/2011/3/checking-the-online-status-with-phonegap-jquery

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean that when `a` is `false` you don't get the `else` part executed? Or that `a` is always `true`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario i mean else part is not executed!!!

Comment: On which device is this an issue? Some [platforms](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Framework/issues/555) have known bugs. According to them, you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator).onLine` as a workaround in the mean time.

Comment: Both ios based and android devices shows this issue....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zvona answer points the issue, but his suggestion (moving the check to the end) is not guarenteed to work.

You need the following code (that waits till Ext has been initialized)

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var a=navigator.onLine;
    if(a){
         alert('online');
    }else{
        Ext.Msg.alert("Alert!", "Please check your internet connection!");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Ext.Msg.alert` before your framework (Sencha / ExtJS) is loaded. Move the `navigator.onLine` checking script to the bottom

Comment: @Fazil - If you've actually fixed the code as suggested and it's still "not working", when JavaScript looks completely broken it's normally due to a syntax error that prevents code from running. Does your environment have a JavaScript console where you can inspect such errors?